# I'm feeling lucky feature for search engines such as Bing and Yahoo

Tags: bing, yahoo-search

Google has the *I'm feeling lucky* thing: http://www.groovypost.com/howto/howto/firefox-4-im-feeling-lucky-addres-bar/

Duck Duck Go has their own version, called ducky. You type in `!` before search term: https://duck.co/forum/thread/4698/google-s-feeling-lucky

Does anyone know how to do the "I'm feeling lucky" search on other engines like Bing and Yahoo?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible with Bing by using their Search API.

Here's a link to one that someone has created via the API:
https://open.blockspring.com/bs/bing-web-search-im-feeling-lucky
That will allow you to search bing with I'm feeling lucky, but you need an API key.

You can get 5,000 free requests here:
https://datamarket.azure.com/dataset/bing/search